# STR DATE with french format sql

Tags: sql, date

i have some date in my db which are like this : 
FCOL_DATE = 31/08/2007 00:00

i'm trying to make this query but i received this error : 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in

```
$from1 = "01/08/2013";
$to1 = "31/08/2013";

foreach ($query=$db->query("SELECT
t1.FCOL_ID, t1.FCOL_FRN_ID, t1.FCOL_DATE, t1.FCOL_PERIODE,
t2.STK_IDFACTCOLISAGE
FROM colisage t1
INNER JOIN mvt_stock t2
ON t1.FCOL_ID = t2.STK_IDFACTCOLISAGE
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(FCOL_DATE, "%d/%m/%Y") BETWEEN $from1 AND $to1 AND t1.FCOL_FRN_ID = $frnId") AS $donnees):
```

Comment: Escape the quotes in the string format as they are interfering with your programming language quotes (or is it just an error in pasting in the code sample)?

Comment: Hey you mean $from1 = 01/08/2013;
$to1 = 31/08/2013; i'm getting the same error :/